# create comment box in woo-commerce shop order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, comment-form

i want to add comment box for Woo-commerce shop order and i am using the below script but its not working.

```
function enable_comments_shop_post_type() {
    add_post_type_support( 'shop_order', 'comments' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'enable_comments_shop_post_type', 11 );
```

Have any idea how to enable comments for shop order ?

Comment: Are you looking for the comments box during checkout? If yes then look in your theme for the woocommerce_checkout_fields filter.. the theme might disable it

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but i want to add comment box on admin shop order and in my account section at order history page , so a customer can chat further with shop manager on their specifics order.

Comment: Thats a default feature of woocommerce.. on the order admin page on the sidebar you have the notes section which can be used to communicate with the customee..

Comment: yes, you are right but customer can't send multiple messages to shop manager, He can send only one time by using checkout order notes fields.